# MYSQL Insert id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the follow doubt

I have 2 tables:

```
id customers
1  alan
2  beth
3  john
```

and

```
id id_customers value
1  1            bar  
2  1            foo
3  2            baz
```

Example:I need to add the value 'alfa' in second table and link this to id 3 from the first.

How i do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into tab2 (id_customers, value)
values ((select id from tab1 where customers='john'), 'alfa');
```

Miss out brackets

Hope it helps

Comment: Work perfect for me. Thank you! I did not find any example that uses select in values

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just do an `insert`?

```
insert into t2 (id_customers, value)
    values (3, 'alfa');
```

This assumes that `id` is auto-incrementing.  If not, you'll need to assign that a value as well.

Based on your comment, use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t2 (id_customers, value)
    select id, 'alfa'
    from t1
    where name = 'john';
```

Comment: i need to search the id by customer name, because this is an varible in my environment