# Finding ID and inserting it into another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns.  ID and WORD.  I've used the following query to insert several files into this table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/xad' IGNORE INTO TABLE words LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1) set word=@col1;
```

Now I'd like to find specific values and insert them into another table.  I know based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297412/mysql-insert-id-from-another-table/44297443?fbclid=IwAR2LUC7do3QjbHVL6BBL3zPwxBA0DxdkJ9avnxwkIPJZiTKTk5tph7Oh1nc) that I can do the following

```
insert into tab2 (id_customers, value)
values ((select id from tab1 where customers='john'), 'alfa');
```

But I'd like to do this based on the files.  For example:

Loop through each line of file xad and pass it's value to a query like the following

```
insert into othertable (word_id)
values ((select id from firsttable where word='VALUE FROM CURRENT LINE OF FILE'));
```

I can write a Java app to do this line by line but I figured it'd be faster to make MySQL do the work if possible.  Is there a way to make MySQL loop over each line, find the ID, and insert it into othertable?

Comment: Yes. You can use [INSERT ... SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). Make the SELECT a join between your imported table and firsttable.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  A `TRIGGER` could be used to *conditionally* copy the id to another table when encountered in whatever loading process is used (`LOAD DATA` / `INSERT .. SELECT ..` / etc).

Plan B:  Simply load the table, *then* copy over the ids that you desire.

Notes:

The syntax for this

```
insert into tab2 (id_customers, value)
values ((select id from tab1 where customers='john'), 'alfa');
```

is more like

```
insert into tab2 (id_customers, value)
    SELECT id, 'alpha'
        FROM tab1
        WHERE customers = 'john'
```